# Tráfego de usuários implica no valor mensal?

Tags: microsoft-azure

Publiquei uma aplicação no Azure, criei um grupo de recursos com um plano, que por exemplo deu 50 dólares/mês.

Esse valor é independente de quantidades de acesso e tráfego? Se 1000 ou 100000 usuário acessam por dia, vai vir o valor diferente na fatura?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diretamente a quantidade de usuários não afetará nada, o que afeta é o tráfego gerado por eles. Então se 1 usuário trafegar 1GB é isso que afetará. Se 100.000 usuários trafegar 1KB cada, estes usuários consumirão bem menos tráfego que aquele único usuário. Aí vai depender do uso que cada usuário pode fazer na sua aplicação específica, das medidas de segurança para evitar abusos (por ataques ou uso excessivo), etc.

No geral há um média de tráfego que cada usuário costuma fazer em uma sessão (o que é outra coisa a se analisar, afinal se o mesmo usuário acessar várias vezes ele provavelmente gerará mais tráfego que um usuário que acessa apenas uma vez) pode ser determinada analisando os *logs* de acesso. É possível fazer estimativas entendendo bem o padrão de tráfego de cada operação, as operações esperadas em cada sessão e a quantidade de sessões/usuários que devem usar. Só o uso real dará uma noção real.

Quanto vai ficar mais caro depende do seu plano, mas provavelmente ficará mais caro sim. Inclusive um dos ataques que se costuma fazer é gerar tráfego fictício para, ou que pode, encarecer a fatura de programadores inexperientes.

Comment: Mas tanto na calculadora de preços quanto na hora de criar o grupo de recursos ou atribuir para a aplicação, em nenhum momento existe essas informações de valor x quantidade de trafego. (ou pelo menos não encontrei)

Comment: Não sei como usou, mas você paga pelo tráfego usado.

Comment: Vlw, o @William forneceu o link na resposta abaixo: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/

Answer (score 1):

Como o @Maniero falou a conta é baseada na quantidade de dados trafegados, não na quantidade de usuários, com base nisso você pode verificar e estimar qual vai ser o custo a ser pago, o valor está [nessa página aqui](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/).

Comment: Isso, era essa página que eu precisava, obrigado, dei a resposta correta ao @bigown, por responder a dúvida, mas seu link me ajudou muito.